# My requirement is to Run multiple executables from the Single program

Tags: multithreading, exec, multiprocess

My requirement is to run multiple executable's from the single program under Linux platform using C/C++.

I have coded running single executable by fork + exec , I am able to run it successfully.

Since exec functions accept the file as a first argument, I am not sure how Can I redirect the output and reading the input and passing cmd like args for the executable. albeit I pass the cmd line as a pass by arguments and found it no change.

Note: The executable's that I need to run had multiple threads running .

```
int status;
pid_t p_pid, c_pid;
const char *path=/home/user/foo"

p_pid = getpid();
c_pid = fork();

switch(c_pid)
{
    case -1:
            perror(" fork failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;

    case 0:
            execv(path, NULL);
            //execv(Pis1_binPath, NULL);
            printf("==%s",strerror(errno));
           // execl(Pis1_binPath, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8);
            break;
    default:
            break;
}

printf("==Parent PID:%d\n",p_pid);
printf("==Child PID:%d\n",c_pid);
```

Answer (score 0):

After the fork(), both processes’ filedescriptors are identical copies.  In the child, you can redirect stdin by:

```
if ((fd = open(“myfile”, O_RDONLY)) > 0) {
    dup2(fd, 0);
    close(fd);
}
```

Obviously, you would want to handle errors properly; this above just avoids the obvious.

By the same vein, you could create a pipe() before the fork, then re-arrange the fd’s so you can control stdin or capture stdout, stderr, etc...

The second argument to execv() is an array of strings which will be copied into ‘argv’ in the new image.